# Magento Change Product View Url Multiple Website Wise

Tags: product, multistore, multi-website

I have created multiple websites in Magento,
and my website's homepages are working fine but When i am trying to view the product from the second website than product redirect to the first website(default).
does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: please try: php bin/magento indexer:reindex